# ✳Two feet six (long)

Tags: grammaticality, singular-vs-plural

Page 709 of *Collins Cobuild English Usage* reads

> If you are expressing size using **feet** and **inches**, you do not
> have to say *inches*, *two **foot** six long*.
>
> However, you can't say ✳two **feet** six.

Firstly, is the adjective *long/deep/etc.* required in *two foot six long*?

Secondly, why is *✳two **feet** six* not admissible?

Comment: Good question, but I don't think there is a clear _why_ to this.  It's just an arbitrary idiom.  It still applies when there are no inches - e.g. "a fifty-foot boat" - so it's more a matter of the length being used as an adjective rather than as a measure.

Comment: There are some good related questions about usage: ["Five foot ten" or "five feet ten"?](/q/120013/44500) and ["6-foot tall" or "6-feet tall"?](/q/176582/44500) - though I don't think there's a detailed examination of origins or logic in either.

Answer (score 2):

> Firstly, is the adjective long/deep/etc. required in two foot six long?

No.

> Secondly, why is ✳two feet six not admissible?

The "X foot Y" construction is very idiomatic. In any other context you would indeed say "two feet" -- "two feet six inches", "two feet and six inches", "two and a half feet", etc.

Comment: 'two foot six' is an informal, conversational way of saying, more formally, 'two feet and six inches' when referring to heights, lengths, depths, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is very frequently used when talking about people's heights (at least in countries where people don't use centimeters), and you almost always leave out the adjective *tall*.

> At **six foot four**, he towered over most of his classmates.

You can even leave out the word *foot* when it's clear from context that you're talking about height:

> Q: How tall are you?
>
> A: I'm **five-six** on a good day.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/five-six#Noun

Comment: @GJC I don't think anyone would interpret the response to "How tall are you?" as anything to do with usury in the Philippines.